# How to access class file in android

Tags: java, android

I want to acess class file from bin folder in android.
I was doing it using

`File f = new File("/bin/filename.class");`

Its working fine in java but in android giving path doesnt work, so
please suggest me other way to access class file of any java file in android.

Comment: add your file in asset folder and access it.

Comment: how can i add files in asset folder at run time ??? Is it feasible ?

Comment: where is your code for accessing those file?

Comment: ClassLoader res = mHelperContext.getClassLoader(); Class[] cs = R.class.getClasses(); for(Class cl : cs) { String n = cl.getName(); Log.i("class name ", n); if(cl.equals(R.class)) { Log.i("class", "found"); } }

Answer (score 2):

You can't access file like

```
File f = new File("/bin/filename.class");
```

from bin folder. **Android can't recognize this path.**

Comment: but i am able to access R.class, R.drwable.class files etc which are of system generated java files. Now, all these files and my class files are placed at same place, if I can access these system generated files then why not my class files ????

Answer (score 1):

Java .class files are converted to Dalvik Executable (.dex), in your apk there won't be any .class files, just one single dex file called classes.dex.

I think this post from Android Developers blog might help you: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Comment: but i am able to access R.class, R.drwable.class files etc which are of system generated java files. Now, all these files and my class files are placed at same place, if I can access these system generated files then why not my class files ????